# How is pre-computation handled by complexity notation?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

Suppose I have an algorithm that runs in $O(n)$ for every input of size $n$, but only after a pre-computation step of $O(n^2)$ for that given size $n.$ Is the algorithm considered $O(n)$ still, with $O(n^2)$ amortized? Or does big O only consider one "run" of the algorithm at size $n$, and so the pre-computation step is included in the notation, making the true complexity $O(n^2+n) = O(n^2)$?

Comment: I think you'll need to give us more details.  What does the precomputation step depend on?  If it doesn't depend on anything, then in the non-uniform model, you can precalculate the results of that precomputation and hardcode them in the algorithm itself.  Read about non-uniform complexity to see about a subtlety in the definition of complexity: e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_complexity#Uniformity; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P/poly.

Comment: I was imagining it depended on $n$, but not any particular input of size $n.$  Like pre-computing a powerset of indices for an array of size $n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand that you have some computational problem with input size $n$, and you use $f(n)$ time for preprocessing. Perhaps after that, you can answer some kind of queries in $g(n)$ time. Both $f$ and $g$ are functions of the input size, and you can now apply Big Oh and say, for instance, that $f(n) = O(n^2)$ and $g(n) = n$.

Now, nobody is forcing you to "consider the runtime to be $O(n)$" or anything like that. So why not just say it like it is, e.g., "after a $O(n^2)$-time preprocessing step, queries can be answered in $O(n)$ time", or "there is an $O(n^2)$-time algorithm for solving the problem", or whatever it is precisely that holds. It's up to you how you present it.

In particular, I want to clear the misconception that "big O would consider one 'run' of the algorithm". If you look at the definition of Big Oh, you'll see that it says nothing about algorithms or their "runs".

Answer (score 0):

When you write about "the complexity", you must write exactly what you are measuring.

In your example, the time for solving one single problem of size n is $O (n^2)$ (actually, it could be better if there is an algorithm that doesn't do the reusable pre-computation and is faster than $O (n^2)$).

The time for solving k problems of size n is $O(n·max(k,n))$. I would say it is very similar to amortized time, but not exactly the same.